# htaccess rewrite rule not showing css,js,iamges

Tags: php, .htaccess

After rewriting rule on htacess file...its not showing css,js,images....

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^business/$ show-business.php [L]
RewriteRule ^business/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ show-business.php?bType=$1
```

If i open show-business.php it shows page. but when i open localhost/abc/business its shows page without images,css,js

Also tried  `<base href="/">` in head section or adding `/` to css files like `/css/style.css`   but not works

Also want to know is the rule i have writeen is correct or not....please give suggestions on good rewrite rules..

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use a `base` element, I suspect your base for you test environment should be `/abc/`?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to be wrong because inside character class a hyphen if it is not at first or last position then it needs to be escaped. You also need to use correct RewriteBase

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/

RewriteRule ^business/?$ show-business.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^business/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ show-business.php?bType=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also make sure to use absolute paths to your CSS, js and images files.

Comment: code have a typo `RewritrBase /abc/` that line should be `RewriteBase /abc/` but it still not shows css,images etc..

Comment: That was a typo and I corrected it. Also can you open your page in Firebug and see for which links you are getting 404 errors.

Comment: Also tell me in which directory have you placed this .htaccess file?

Comment: in abc folder where all files are placed and eorros are showing fr all files like css,js etcc

Comment: And did you check Firebug to see which URLs are showing 404 to you?